# Store setdiff results in dataframe cell

Tags: r, dplyr, set-difference, rowwise

Here is my example:

```
library(dplyr)
my_df <- data.frame( col_1 = I(list(c(1,2), 1 )), col_2 = c(1,2))
my_df <- my_df %>% rowwise(diff = setdiff(col_1, col_2))
```

It generates an error:

```
Error in rowwise(., diff = setdiff(col_1, col_2)) : 
  unused argument (diff = setdiff(col_1, col_2))
```

What is wrong and how to fix it? Any thoughts?

Update: my bad, I simply forgot to add `mutate`

```
my_df <- data.frame( col_1 = I(list(c(1,2), 1 )), col_2 = c(1,2))
my_df <- my_df %>% rowwise() %>% mutate(diff = setdiff(col_1, col_2))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option is `map2` as both columns are `list`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
my_df %>%
     mutate(diff = map2(col_1, col_2, setdiff))
```

---

Or if we need to use `rowwise`

```
my_df %>%
    rowwise %>% 
    mutate(diff = setdiff(col_1, col_2))
```